# CSS transition rotate issues on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxh06n1w/1/) (it's not a good example, in Chrome number 2 is displayed, but with IE number 2 doesn't display) .

```css
.flip {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .22s;
  -ms-transition: none;
  transition: transform .22s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: none;
}
.flippe,
.flop {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.flippe {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px);
  transform: translateZ(90px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(90px);
}
.flop {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-110px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-110px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-110px);
}
.flip:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip">
  <div class="flippe">1</div>
  <div class="flop">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try adding property without vendor prefix?

Comment: without -ms ? Yes i have already try that but not work

Comment: The correct order is prefixed rules first and non-prefixed last.

Comment: IE does not support the preserve-3d property but I don't know if that answers your problem.